# How to use margin as property of WPF usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

How to use margin as property of WPF usercontrol?

```
    public Double pCusSPAge
    {
        get
        {
            return btnCusSPAge.Margin.Left;
        }
        set
        {
            btnCusSPAge.Margin = new Thickness(value);
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("pCusSPAge"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. UserControls already have a margin property.

Answer (score 1):

UserControl have a Margin Property and you use it like this...

to set it:

```
        Thickness newMargin = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1); //just an example
        UserControl.Margin = newMargin;
```

to get it:

```
        Thickness newMargin = new Thickness(); 
        newMargin = UserControl.Margin;
```

Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: BTW: What that initialization of Margin in the latter piece of code is for?